# Which pronunciation of “kun” is correct or what’s the difference?

Tags: pronunciation

There are two audio recordings that I am listening to both have different pronunciations of the pinyin “kun”.

- One is from [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/pronunciation/Kun).
- And another is from [a pinyin audio chart](https://www.yoyochinese.com/chinese-learning-tools/Mandarin-Chinese-pronunciation-lesson/pinyin-chart-table).

Which pronunciation should I be following or which is more standard for stuff like HSK?

Comment: I didn't find any differences in these two pronunciations.

Comment: The audio recordings are both correct, and are essentially the same k-uen aka [kʰu̯ən] in IPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the Chinese pinyin "kun" sounds like "kwen".

If you like to take a further look at the the pronunciation, you can see [Zhuyin(Bopomofo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bopomofo), which we often use it in Taiwan: ㄎㄨㄣ

ㄎ / ㄨ / ㄣ

k / wu / en

BTW, I think those two audio sounds familiar.

Comment: For some reason one of them sounds like “kwen” and another sounds like “koon”

Comment: kwen is the correct one.

Comment: These are called allophones, which are different sounds that represent the same phoneme.